# Test API Grails

Tags: rest, api, grails, groovy

I try to get JSON from URL at HTTPBuilder, but this code return an Exception, return this erro "Method threw 'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException' exception."

```
static request(String path, boolean isGet){
    def myClient = new HTTPBuilder("${HOST}${path}")
    def jsonResp = [:]

    try{
        if(isGet){
            log.info "[EXAMPLE GET] ${HOST}${path}"
            myClient.get(requestContentType: ContentType.JSON){ resp, json ->
                jsonResp = resp
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        println "erro: "
        log.info "[EXAMPLE ERROR]: ${e.message}"
        println(e.message)
    }
    jsonResp
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the MissingPropertyException on?

I tried your example in a script (with a few mods), this time returning json rather than resp which seems to work.

```
import groovy.transform.Field
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

@Field final String HOST = 'http://echo.jsontest.com'

def resp = request( "/name/jon", true )
println resp.toString()


def request(String path, boolean isGet){

    def myClient = new HTTPBuilder("${HOST}${path}")
    def jsonResp = [:]

    try{
        if(isGet){
            println  "[EXAMPLE GET] ${HOST}${path}"
            myClient.get(requestContentType: ContentType.JSON){ resp, json ->
            jsonResp = json
        }
    }
} 
catch(Exception e) {
      println(e.message)
    }
    jsonResp
```

}

Output is:

```
{"name":"jon"}
```